# Communicating between a python and electron app

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, electron

I have a python app which needs a serious GUI lift so I've decided to use electron.

I have compiled my python app into an executable (.exe) which takes in arguments. On electron, the user will input and the executable will be sent that input as an argument to process it.

How would I tell electron what is happening behind the scenes in the executable.

My original thought was to make the executable write to a file and make electron read that file but that would probably end up corrupting the file instead when trying to read and write from the file.

Comment: Electron is a web browser, and Python is (sort of) a systems programming language. Why not speak in HTTP? Electron could make AJAX calls from either the front or back end to a Python Webserver. If Electron made a request with query params (GET) or a body (POST) matching the args you want to pass to your Python program. The Python server can then reply in JSON with the result. Electron can then parse the JSON and use the result. This might be of help to you: https://medium.com/@onejohi/building-a-simple-rest-api-with-python-and-flask-b404371dc699
If not try other REST API tutorials.

Comment: SO is really harsh to new comers. I think PO's question has its values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a python script/program inside your electron app. This way, you can control the status of the operation in electron and update the UI accordingly. [here is an example of what I'm talking about](https://www.techiediaries.com/python-electron-tutorial/).

If that's not a possibility, you could consider using a communication channel (webosckets for example) to interface between the two applications, sending status from one to another. [Something like a RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call).

Comment: thanks alot, I'll try looking into this. I'll wait for some people to drop their opinion and will put the answer check after that ;3

Comment: The link is expired, can you send me some link to refer ?